# Rotating A image with a button (Android)

Tags: java, android, button, rotation

I have a image on my view I need a button, that when the button is clicked the image will start rotating on its center point by 1px at a time.

Right now I have another button that moves the image down, by adding 1 px to the top margin. Here is that code:

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams()).topMargin += 1;
                image.requestLayout();
```

I just need to basically do the same thing, but rather then moving the image down, i need to rotate it.

Comment: What about `image.setRotation(angle);`?

Comment: Could i set it to run when the button is pressed, and rotate on its center point?  How should i do this?

Comment: Just call it inside the Button clickListener.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put this in your code: `image.setRotation(image.getRotation() + 1);`

finally your code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams()).topMargin += 1;
                image.setRotation(image.getRotation() + 1);
                image.requestLayout();
```